# How can I group numbers in a list by their number of digits

Tags: java, grouping

So my problem is that I do not know how to sort a `Map<<Integer, List<Integer>>` by length.

For example you have the list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407],

and the answer should be {1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3=[153, 370, 371, 407]}

I wrote the code for the armstrong number (armstrongs)

```
    List<Integer> lance = armstrongs(500); 
    System.out.println(lance); 
    // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407]

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> grouped = groupByLength(lance);
    System.out.println(grouped);
    // {1=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3=[153, 370, 371, 407]}
```

My question is, how can i sort the list by length with the length number?

the only thing that i have is

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupByLength(List<Integer> x){
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) operations are well suited for this kind of problem. In particular, method [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) does exactly what you need: it creates an object that *collects* all the elements in the list-backed stream into a map that maps a *classifier* (in your case the number of digits) to a list of the elements grouped by that classifier.

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupByLength(List<Integer> x) {
    return x.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(n -> Integer.toString(n).length()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will only have a maximum of three digits, you can try some code like this (untested);

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupByLength(List<Integer> x){
    List<Integer> group1 = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> group2 = new LinkedList<>();
    List<Integer> group3 = new LinkedList<>();
    Map <Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++){
        int length = String.valueOf(x.get(i)).length();
        if(length = 1){
            group1.add(x.get(i));
        }else if(length = 2){
            group2.add(x.get(i));
        }else{
            group3.add(x.get(i));
        }
    }

    if(group1.size()>0)
        map.put(1,group1);
    if(group2.size()>0)
        map.put(2,group2);
    if(group3.size()>0)
        map.put(3,group3);
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are computing Armstrong numbers that is important information as you already have your `length` value.

One of the advantages of `streams` is that they eliminate intermediate containers and allow processing of values as the are presented.  In your situation you calculated Armstrong numbers, put them into a List and **then** put them into a map.

Perhaps a better way, depending on your requirements is to put them into a map as you calculate them.  You can also collect them in a list at the same time if you need to.

To calculate Armstrong numbers, you already have a length `len` since you need to raise individual digits to that power.  So you should use it to categorize your numbers.

Allocate your `HashMap`

```java
 Map<Integer, List<Integer<> arms = new HashMap<>();
```

Then as you calculate your Armstrong numbers, do the following.

```java
`len` is length of number
`arm_number` is your latest Armstrong number

    map.compute(len,
                  (k, v) -> v == null ? new ArrayList<>()
                        : v).add(arm_number);
```

The above, uses the key `len` to see if the list exists.  It either returns that list or creates a new one.  The `.add` then adds the number to that list.

By doing it on the fly you are saving time and still getting your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect example where Streams are very good for this kind of problem. With Streams, you can do this in a few lines of code:

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groupByLength(List<Integer> x){
    return x.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                (Integer i) -> Integer.toString(i).length(), // Grouping by length
                TreeMap::new, // Lengths are sorted
                Collectors.toList())); // Each group is List<Integer>
}
```